# (1 week into learning Swift) Is it ok to compute(?) inside the body?

Tags: swift, swiftui, text, set

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var fiveNumbers: Set<Int> = []
    @State private var twoNumbers: Set<Int> = []
    // there has to be a better way to copy a Set instead of making it a string like this. it includes brackets too....
    // options: remove all [] from string OR find another way to get the numbers into the boxes without being a string
    @State private var fiveSentence = ""
    @State private var twoSentence = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Button("Faz o meu Euromilhões") {
                    fiveNumbers.removeAll()
                    twoNumbers.removeAll()
                    
                    while fiveNumbers.count < 5 {
                        let newRandomNumber = Int.random(in: 1...50)
                            fiveNumbers.insert(newRandomNumber)
                    }
                    let sortedNumbers = fiveNumbers.sorted()
                    fiveSentence = "\(sortedNumbers)"
                    
                    while twoNumbers.count < 2 {
                        let newRandomNumber = Int.random(in: 1...12)
                            twoNumbers.insert(newRandomNumber)
                    }
                    let sortedTwoNumbers = twoNumbers.sorted()
                    twoSentence = "\(sortedTwoNumbers)"
                }
                
                Section("Números") {
                    Text(fiveSentence)
                }
                Section("Estrelas") {
                    Text(twoSentence)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Euromilhões")
            .toolbar {
                if !fiveNumbers.isEmpty {
                    Button("Limpar") {
                        fiveSentence.removeAll()
                        twoSentence.removeAll()
                        fiveNumbers.removeAll()
                        twoNumbers.removeAll()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me preface this by saying I have no experience in coding and I'm an absolute beginner. This is a throwaway project I'm tinkering with after 1 week of 100 days of Swift.

*- Q1: Is this ok, or should I compute (not sure if this is the correct term?) outside of the body for the button:*

`Button("Faz o meu Euromilhões")`

*Q2: I tried to be "smart" and use*

- `@State private var fiveNumbers: Set<Int> = []`

instead of

- `@State private var fiveNumbers: [Int] = []`

to avoid having to write more code to not get repeated numbers. `if !fiveNumbers.contain(newRandomNumber) { fiveNumbers.append(newRandomNumber) }`

but how can I get the array into `Text` without brackets?

Thank you so much for your time and patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: The way you are doing it is formally “okay”. It does not violate the way SwiftUI works. You are not really computing inside the `body` of `ContentView`. Instead, you are passing a “closure” (a function) to the `Button`. The `Button` saves the closure and runs it later, when it (the `Button`) is tapped. That’s when the computation happens.

The way you are doing it is also “okay” for a toy project, where you don’t intend to keep the code around for a long time and you don’t intend to write test cases.

If this were a serious project, you would want to factor that code out into a standalone function so that you could write tests for it.

Q2: Here’s one way to turn a `Set<Int>` into a `Text`:

```
        Text(
            fiveNumbers
                .sorted()
                .formatted(ListFormatStyle(memberStyle: .number))
        )
```

Here’s another way:

```
        Text(
            fiveNumbers
                .sorted()
                .map { "\($0)"}
                .joined(separator: ", ")
        )
```

Comment: regarding Q2 it now displays number "and" other number. How can I have it separated by a coma like all numbers before last? Thank you

Comment: I have added that to my answer.